# Stateless Event Listeners in React Redux

Tags: redux, flux

I need to add functionality into my react/redux application that is event based.

I'm using redux and I have reducers that change my application state on events through actions. Some actions for example: (USER_CLICKED_BUTTON, AJAX_CALL_STARTED, AJAX_CALL_ERROR, AJAX_CALL_SUCCESS)

I want to add listeners to these events and do some work that isn't state related, specifically, call another API like analytics.

Does it make sense to add another "reducer" with no real state, that simply listens to these actions and acts (for example call ga(...)?)

something like this:

```
var Actions  = require ('../actions/actionTypes');

var gaReducer = function(state, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case Actions.USER_CLICKED_BUTTON: 
               ga('send', 'event', 'user-clicked-button');
               break;
    }

    return state;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good case for middleware. Check out https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger for an example.

Then your store might look something like:

```
const middleware = [
  myAnalyticsMiddleware()
];

export default createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

Comment: Ok, this sent me in the right direction, this is probably more like what I'm looking for: https://github.com/ezekielchentnik/redux-reporter.

Comment: also, I don't see how that example applies to my problem.

Comment: The example applies because it hooks into the store and does something (in this case logging, in your case it would be sending analytics) when the store changes.